# Flask - Get requests with json parameter using cURL

Tags: python, rest, api, curl, flask

I have developped a simple REST API using the python library `flask`. Here is an example of what I am doing:

```py
from flask import Flask, request
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    json_arg = json.loads(request.args.get("json_arg", None))
    non_json_arg = request.args.get("non_json_arg", None)
    return "Hello, your json arg is: %s and your non_json_arg is %s"%(json_arg, non_json_arg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

To test my code, I have written a python client this way:

```py
import requests
import json

json_arg = [
            {
                "0": 1.3,
                "1": 1.4
            },
            {
                "0": 5.3,
                "1": 40.5
            }
        ]
non_json_arg = "some_arg"

arguments = {
    "json_arg": json.dumps(json_arg),
    "non_json_arg": non_json_arg
}

r = requests.get("http://localhost:5000", params=arguments, headers={"content-type": "application/json"})

print(r.text)
```

This works just fine and the output is:

```
Hello, your json arg is: [{u'1': 1.4, u'0': 1.3}, {u'1': 40.5, u'0': 5.3}] and your non_json_arg is some_arg
```

For test reasons, I want to do the same thing with cURL, what I have tested so far is:

```
curl -X GET --data '{"json_arg": [ { "0": 1.3, "1": 1.4 }, { "0": 5.3, "1": 40.5 } ], "non_json_arg":"some_arg"}' http://localhost:5000
```

But this return an error:

```
....
>> json_arg = json.loads(request.args.get("json_arg", None))
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

I have tested a lot of other arguments of `cURL` but I can't find an answer for this simple question:

*How to send a GET request to an API with json arguments?*

Answer (score 0):

Typically one would use a POST request for that rather than a get request. So it would look like this:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"json_arg": [ { "0": 1.3, "1": 1.4 }, { "0": 5.3, "1": 40.5 } ], "non_json_arg":"some_arg"}' http://localhost:5000
```

However if you do want to use a GET request you would need to use the params in the actual url so it would look something like:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:5000/?json_arg=%5B%7B%220%22%3A+1.3%2C+%221%22%3A+1.4%7D%2C+%7B%220%22%3A+5.3%2C+%221%22%3A+40.5%7D%5D&non_json_arg=some_arg
```

I would suggest typically one would use a POST request for sending JSON data.

Comment: an example of a curl request to the api above?

Comment: `curl -X GET http://localhost:5000/?json_arg=%5B%7B%220%22%3A+1.3%2C+%221%22%3A+1.4%7D%2C+%7B%220%22%3A+5.3%2C+%221%22%3A+40.5%7D%5D&non_json_arg=some_arg`

Comment: Can you edit your question to add this comment so I can accept the answer? this will help others :)